# How to insert all occurances in list[] into CompositeVideoClip

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking, moviepy

I have a video where I want to insert a dynamic amount of TextClip(s). I have a while loop that handles the logic for actually creating the different TextClips and giving them individual durations & start_times (this works). I do however have a problem with actually "compiling" the video itself with inserting these texts.

Code for creating a TextClip (that works).

```py
text = mpy.TextClip(str(contents),
    color='white', size=[1700, 395], method='caption').set_duration(
                   int(list[i - 1])).set_start(currentTime).set_position(("center", 85)) 

print(str(i) + " written")
textList.append(text)
```

Code to "compile" the video. (that doesn't work)

```
final_clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip, len(textList)])
final_clip.write_videofile("files/final/TEST.mp4")
```

I tried several approaches but now I'm stuck and can't figure out a way to continue. Before I get a lot of "answers" telling me to do a while loop on the compiling, let me just say that the actual compiling takes about 5 minutes and I have 100-500 different texts I need implemented in the final video which would take days. Instead I want to add them one by one and then do 1 big final compile which I know it will take slightly longer than 5 minutes, but still a lot quicker than 2-3 days.

For those of you that may not have used moviepy before I will post a snippet of "my code" that actually works, not in the way I need it to though.

```
final_clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip, textList[0], textList[1], textList[2]])
final_clip.write_videofile("files/final/TEST.mp4")
```

This works exactly as intended (adding 3 texts), However I dont/can't know how many texts there will be in each video beforehand so I need to somehow insert a dynamic amount of **textList[]** into the function.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure what the arguments after `clip,` do (you could clarify), but if the problem's solved by inserting a variable number of `textList[i]` args, the solution's simple:

```
CompositeVideoClip([clip, *textList])
```

The star *unpacks* the list (or any *iterable*); ex: `arg=4,5` -- `def f(a,b): return a+b` -- `f(*arg)==9`. If you have *many* `textList`s, you can manage them via a nested list or a dictionary:

```
textListDict = {'1':textList1, '2':textList2, ...}
textListNest = [textList1, textList2, ...] # probably preferable - using for below

# now iterate:
for textList in textListNest:
    final_clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip, *textList])
```

---

**Unpacking demo**:

```py
def show_then_join(a, b, c):
    print("a={}, b={}, c={}".format(a,b,c))
    print(''.join("{}{}{}".format(a,b,c)))

some_list = [1, 2, 'dog']
show_then_sum(*some_list) # only one arg is passed in, but is unpacked into three
# >> a=1, b=2, c=dog
# >> 12dog
```

Comment: the argument after "clip," are the textfields. So clip is basically my "video/background" while textList [] is a list containing all textClips with duration & start_time added individually. So *textList would unpack my list and therefore insert each value inside? 

Lets say I have a list with 3 values aka [1], [2] & [3].
If I write *textList[] it would then insert the following text "textList[1], textList[2], textList[3]. Do I understand you correct? I can't test at the moment but will try in a few hours.

Comment: @Xetra That's correct; see demo above. Similar to the demo, your function will automatically handle the unpacking, as it expects a variable number of inputs for `textList`

Comment: Thank you a lot for both answering my question, but also spending the extra time to show me a demo. This helped me not only to solve the problem but actually "upped my python" by a lot. I read up on unpacking lists after your question and I learned a lot.

Comment: @Xetra Python has lots of neat and highly useful tricks that I myself have learned only recently - glad the problem's solved. Consider also upvoting -- good luck.